# Run entire bash script as root or use sudo on the commands that need it?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I'm working on some installation script in bash (on a Raspberry Pi running Stretch). It will copy files to `/usr/local/bin` and to my user profile and it will install a few packages if  needed. The script is almost 2000 lines and 20–30 commands need root.

Now my question is: should I run the entire script with `sudo` or just as standard user and sudo only the commands inside the script that need admin rights?

Comment: If you sure that your script is completely right and it correctly handles exception events, you can freely you `sudo` to entire one. But from good security practice side and Unix ideology, you must use min permissions as much as possible and upper it only in cases when it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure that running the script with `sudo` won't do you any harm (For example, it won't create new files that will now need `root` privileges, but wouldn't otherwise), you should run it with `sudo`.

If you know there are some side effects or you are unsure, do it the safe way and use `sudo` just where you must.

Comment: Until now I run it as root, setting appropriate permissions for the logged on user. This works fine, but I still doubt if this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

At the header of script put this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Detects if script are not running as root... 
if [ "$UID" != "0" ]; then
   #$0 is the script itself (or the command used to call it)...
   #$* parameters...
   if whereis sudo &>/dev/null; then
     echo "Please type the sudo password for the user $USER"
     sudo $0 $*
     exit
   else
     echo "Sudo not found. You will need to run this script as root."
     exit
   fi 
fi
```

Comment: I know it's unsafe, but on raspberry pi, root has no password. So I get the question to enter the sudo password and just proceeds. Is there a way to detect if a password is set, just to skip the question?

Comment: Hmmm sudo password is not root password, is your user without password or really is root without password? Are you using sudo or su to login as root?

Comment: I login with user pi (with password) - sudo doesn't require password.

Comment: Are you saying that it requests a password for you but you just need to press ENTER?

Comment: Hello? Are you there?

Comment: No, sudo doesn't ask for password. It is by default on raspbian

Comment: but you say that: "So I get the question to enter the sudo password and just proceeds." are you talking about the script i wrote?

Comment: Yes, your script. It echoes "Please type the sudo..." but `sudo $0 $*` runs without password. I find this confusing for the user, so that's why I asked if there is a way to detect this and to suppress the message.

Comment: Wait a minute i will fix it! Ops, please wait a day, only tomorrow i will fix it.

Comment: 1. You should use `"$@"` instead of `$*`. 2. Put `exec` before sudo for a nicer process tree.